# Regular Expression admits more numbers that allowed

Tags: regex, vb.net

Could you help me with this regular Expression please, it is supposed to allow these numbers: 123.56, 1.26, 12.36 but it admits 12345.56 12345.26...so instead of allow only three numbers before the point it admits five numbers.

this is my regular expression, the validation is on VB.NET, could you help me to fix it please

```
Dim Vestatura As String = "^[0-9]{1,3}((.)[0-9]{1,2})?$"
        Dim Evaluar As Regex = New Regex(Vestatura)
        Dim match As Match = Evaluar.Match(txtCMS.Text)
```

Comment: This shouldn't match `12345.56`. Anyway, just escape the dot as it has special meaning in regex (of any character).

Comment: The supplied regex will match 3 digits, anything, and then upto 2 digits, so a 6 character wide string.

123Q12 for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the dot in-order to match a literal dot character. Because an unescaped dot would match any character.

```
Dim Vestatura As String = "^[0-9]{1,3}(([.])[0-9]{1,2})?$"
```

or

```
Dim Vestatura As String = "^[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this string

```
^\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,2})?$
```

According to https://regex101.com/, using that string against this data ...

```
1
12
123
1234
1.
12.
123.
1234.
1.1
12.1
123.1
1234.1
1.12
12.12
123.12
1234.12
1.123
12.123
123.123
1234.123
```

using the modifiers `gm`, results in the following strings matching ...

```
1
12
123
1.1
12.1
123.1
1.12
12.12
123.12
```

and these not matching ...

```
1234
1.
12.
123.
1234.
1234.1
1234.12
1.123
12.123
123.123
1234.123
```

Hope that's of use.